# How to parallelize the for loop while scp the files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, scp

I am running my below shell script from `machineA` which is copying the files `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA`. If the files are not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC`.

The below shell script will copy the files into `TEST1` and `TEST2` directory in `machineA`..

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

readonly TEST1=/data01/test1
readonly TEST2=/data02/test2
readonly SERVER_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly FILE_LOCATION=/data/snapshot

dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${SERVER_LOCATION[0]} ls -dt1 "$FILE_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${SERVER_LOCATION[1]} ls -dt1 "$FILE_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

echo $dir1
echo $dir2

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ]
then
    rm -rf $TEST1/*
    rm -rf $TEST2/*
    for el in $test1_partition
    do
        scp david@${SERVER_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/pp_monthly_9800_"$el"_200003_5.data $TEST1/. || scp david@${SERVER_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/pp_monthly_9800_"$el"_200003_5.data $TEST1/.
    done
    for sl in $test2_partition
    do    
        scp david@${SERVER_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/pp_monthly_9800_"$sl"_200003_5.data $TEST2/. || scp david@${SERVER_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/pp_monthly_9800_"$sl"_200003_5.data $TEST2/.
    done
fi
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53390/is-there-a-way-to-run-process-parallelly-in-the-loop-of-a-bash-script

Currently it copies the file from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA` `TEST1` directory first, and if it is done, then only it will go and copy the files from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA` `TEST2` directory.. Is there any way I transfer the files both in `TEST1` and `TEST2` directory simultaneously?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
done
```

with

```
done &
```

This will start the two for-loops in the background.

And finish the script with:

```
wait
```

This will wait for the two for-loops to complete.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. What does `wait` do here? It will wait for the script to finish before exiting out from the script correct?

Comment: And the file transfer will happened in the background. It's just that, control won't come out of the script?

Comment: wait will wait for all child processes to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
PROCESSES=4  # Number of threads you want
for item in ${LIST}; do
    ACTION ${item} &
    while (( $(jobs |wc -l) >= (( ${PROCESSES} + 1 )) )); do
        sleep 0.1
    done
done
wait
```

This will work through your items in LIST and execute ACTION against item in the background.

Then it checks to see how many jobs are still running and waits until you're not threadcapped to continue.